# Relation "active_storage_attachments" does not exist for PG database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I have a Rails project I am trying to deploy to Heroku and I am getting the following error:

[image]

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "active_storage_attachments" does not exist

I've looked at previous questions regarding this issue and I have tried the following things:

- resetting my database and running the migration files again
- running 'rails active_storage:install'

I am using the following dependencies, and I have configured ActiveStorage to use Amazon S3:

[image]

Comment: Maybe stupid question, but just to be sure: did you run your migrations on Heroku? `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: @bo-oz I rerun all my migration files in Heroku